# Entity Framework error using DefaultIfEmpty()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, defaultifempty

I have a problem with Entity Framework using the DefaultIfEmpty method. The following query is returning empty when it should return an offer that matches all criteria in the database.

If I remove one or both `DefaultIfEmpty` method calls it works, but with them it doesn't. I need those to prevend another problem in the query.

When I execute the generated SQL query directly on the database it works and it returns the offer.

I also made an Unit Test reproducing the same example and it also passes so it must be an Entity Framework issue.

Here's the query:

```
private static Expression<Func<Offer, bool>> AddFilter(Service criteria)
{
        return offer => offer.Restrictions.

        SelectMany(rest => rest.OperatorRange.DefaultIfEmpty(), (rest, alop) => new { Restriction = rest, OperatorRange = alop.Id }).
        Where(alop => criteria.ServiceUseNet == null || alop.OperatorRange.ToUpper() == criteria.ServiceUseNet.ToUpper()).

        SelectMany(rest => rest.Restriction.CallType.DefaultIfEmpty(), (rest, till) => new { Restriction = rest, CallType = till.Id }).
        Any(till => criteria.UseServiceCoverage == null || till.CallType.ToUpper() == criteria.UseServiceCoverage.ToUpper());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it into two `Any` calls:

```
return offer => offer.Restrictions
    .Any(rest
        => rest.OperatorRange
                .Where(alop => criteria.ServiceUseNet == null
                             || alop.OperatorRange.ToUpper() == criteria.ServiceUseNet.ToUpper())
        .Any(till => criteria.UseServiceCoverage == null
                  || till.CallType.ToUpper() == criteria.UseServiceCoverage.ToUpper()));
```

The predicate is supposed to test whether there are *any* `OperatorRange`s (meeting some criteria) having *any* `CallType`s meeting some criteria. If there are no `OperatorRange`s, there won't be any `CallType`s either, let alone matching `CallType`s.

In this form, the predicate always returns true or false.

Comment: The solution you are saying has a problem, because I need the query to generate two `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s and if I do that the query will generate an `INNER JOIN` and then a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: I tried to explain that the first outer join doesn't add anything.

Comment: The thing is, I need both to be `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, because if the criteria for the first filter returns null, then no matter the value of the criteria of the other filter, the query will return null also.

Comment: It can be done by two `Any` calls, please see the edit.

Comment: I've found another solution, using `if` s to determine the value of the criteria for each filter and returning a different query depending on that.

However the solution you posted also works, the only issues there would be that that would affect the performance, and that it wouldn't work on an Oracle 11 database.

Comment: Yes, that's another issue I didn't want to address (yet). The 2 `Any`s are still applicable, also with the conditionally built queries. It's a bit more concise than `SelectMany`.